# Is there an idiomatic go way to print string pointer contents or nil?

Tags: go

I have a string pointer that may or may not be nil, and I want to print out either the contents of the string if contents exist, or indicate that the pointer is nil if it is nil.  Is there a clever way to do this that doesn't involve either an if check or a temporary variable (preferably a single line)?

Right now I'm using something like this:

```
if p == nil {
    fmt.Print(p)
} else {
    fmt.Print(*p)
}
```

But this is particularly awkward and verbose when there is other formatting and other variables that are intended to be printed before and/or after that value.

Comment: if you have a string pointer that's already not very idiomatic... but no, there's no way to do that better than how you did it.

Comment: Well, you could write a function for this...

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer One of example of why I have string pointers is unmarshalling json data with optional string fields.  Another is the aws-sdk-go library, which makes extensive use of pointers (probably also because of json under the hood; I haven't looked).  Either way, "stop using pointers" is not an available choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
func main() {
    var hello SmartString = "hello"

    p := &hello
    p.Print()
    p = nil
    p.Print()

}

type SmartString string

func (p *SmartString) Print() {
    if p == nil {
        fmt.Println(p)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(*p)
    }
}
```

Whether it's a good idea or not is up to you.

You can even use the String interface to make it work with `fmt.Println`

```
func main() {
    var hello SmartString = "hello"

    p := &hello
    fmt.Println(p)
    p = nil
    fmt.Println(p)

}

type SmartString string

func (p *SmartString) String() string {
    if p == nil {
        return "<nil>"
    }
    return string(*p)
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but it does appear to be the best available option.  Thanks.

Comment: If your rename the `Print` method to `String` and make it return a string instead of writing to stdout, you'll implement the `Stringer` interface, which might be more useful.

Comment: is there some `%?` expresion to just print string value under pointer?